# Android customer adpter scrolling issue

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view

i am going to display detail with fixed title invno date etc in textview. while below is listview which display with customer adpter and in last of line display with total with diffrent color in customer adpter[image]

but when i scrol two three time is cause problem like this [image]

this is my customeAdpter

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    private RelativeLayout relativeCel;
    private ArrayList<String> listidA=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> listDateA=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> lisTotalAMTA=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> listPaymenIdA=new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> listPaymenNameA=new ArrayList<String>();
    private Float total=0.0f;


    /**
     * 
     * @param a
     * @param listid
     * @param listDate
     * @param lisTotalAMT
     * @param listPaymenId
     * @param listPaymenName
     */
    public CustomAdapter(Activity a,ArrayList<String>listid,ArrayList<String>listDate,ArrayList<String>lisTotalAMT,ArrayList<String>listPaymenId,ArrayList<String>listPaymenName) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)a.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.activity=a;
        this.listidA=listid;
        this.listDateA=listDate;
        this.lisTotalAMTA=lisTotalAMT;
        this.listPaymenIdA=listPaymenId;
        this.listPaymenNameA=listPaymenName;
        total=0.0f;

        for(int i=0;i<listidA.size();i++)
            total=total+(Float.parseFloat(""+lisTotalAMTA.get(i)));

    }
    public int getCount() {
        return listidA.size()+1;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView txtInvoiceNo,txtDate,txtPaymentMode ,txtPamentAmount;
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            AppLog.logString(TAG+"if Null: "+position);
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.item_sales_report, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtInvoiceNo = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtInvoiceNo);
            holder.txtDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtDate);
            holder.txtPaymentMode = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPaymentMode); 
            holder.txtPamentAmount = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtPamentAmount);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            AppLog.logString(TAG+"else Null: "+position);
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        if(position-1==listPaymenIdA.size()-1){
            //AppLog.logString(TAG+"if: "+position);
            int color=getResources().getColor(R.color._90ffffff);
            holder.txtInvoiceNo.setBackgroundColor(color);
            holder.txtDate.setBackgroundColor(color);
            holder.txtPamentAmount.setBackgroundColor(color);
            holder.txtPaymentMode.setBackgroundColor(color);

            holder.txtInvoiceNo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.txtDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.txtPamentAmount.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            holder.txtPaymentMode.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            holder.txtInvoiceNo.setText("");
            holder.txtDate.setText("Total ");
            holder.txtPamentAmount.setText(""+round(total));
            holder.txtPaymentMode.setText("");
        }else{
            //AppLog.logString(TAG+"else: "+position);
            Date date1 = null;
            try {
                date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(listDateA.get(position));
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            formatterYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
            String todaye = formatterYY.format(date1);
            holder.txtInvoiceNo.setText(""+listidA.get(position));
            holder.txtDate.setText(""+todaye);
            holder.txtPaymentMode.setText(""+listPaymenNameA.get(position));
            holder.txtPamentAmount.setText(""+round(lisTotalAMTA.get(position)));
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just change with

```
if(position-1==listPaymenIdA.size()-1){
        //AppLog.logString(TAG+"if: "+position);
        int color=getResources().getColor(R.color._90ffffff);
        holder.txtInvoiceNo.setBackgroundColor(color);
        holder.txtDate.setBackgroundColor(color);
        holder.txtPamentAmount.setBackgroundColor(color);
        holder.txtPaymentMode.setBackgroundColor(color);

        holder.txtInvoiceNo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.txtDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.txtPamentAmount.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        holder.txtPaymentMode.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

        holder.txtInvoiceNo.setText("");
        holder.txtDate.setText("Total ");
        holder.txtPamentAmount.setText(""+round(total));
        holder.txtPaymentMode.setText("");
    }else{
        //AppLog.logString(TAG+"else: "+position);
        Date date1 = null;
        try {
            date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(listDateA.get(position));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int color=getResources().getColor(R.color._10ffffff);//normal color which display
        holder.txtInvoiceNo.setBackgroundColor(color);
        holder.txtDate.setBackgroundColor(color);
        holder.txtPamentAmount.setBackgroundColor(color);
        holder.txtPaymentMode.setBackgroundColor(color);

        holder.txtInvoiceNo.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.txtDate.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.txtPamentAmount.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);
        holder.txtPaymentMode.setTypeface(null, Typeface.NORMAL);

        formatterYY = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.US);
        String todaye = formatterYY.format(date1);
        holder.txtInvoiceNo.setText(""+listidA.get(position));
        holder.txtDate.setText(""+todaye);
        holder.txtPaymentMode.setText(""+listPaymenNameA.get(position));
        holder.txtPamentAmount.setText(""+round(lisTotalAMTA.get(position)));
    }
```